# resolving this responsiveness frontend bootstrap

Tags: html, css, layout, bootstrap-5, responsive

I want the "stats-item" responsive and display them in two columns on mobile view, not 1 column

Desktop View:

[image: desktop view]

Mobile View:

[image: mobile view]

Here is my HTML, I have utilized the HTML class `<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6">` to facilitate the creation of a responsive grid layout.

```css
.stats-counters .stats-item {
  background-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: 0px 0 30px rgba(82, 86, 94, 0.05);
  padding: 30px;
  display: flex;
  /* Use Flexbox to keep them in a horizontal row */
  align-items: center;
  /* Align items vertically center */
  justify-content: center;
  /* Center the content horizontally */
}

.stats-counters .stats-item i {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  /* You can adjust this value as needed */
  line-height: 0;
  margin-right: 20px;
  color: var(--color-primary);
}

.stats-counters .stats-item span {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  /* You can adjust this value as needed */
  font-weight: 600;
  color: var(--color-primary);
}

.stats-counters .stats-item p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: var(--font-primary);
  font-size: 1em;
  /* You can adjust this value as needed */
}


/* Media query for mobile view */

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .stats-counters .stats-item {
    flex-basis: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<!-- Body -->
<section id="hero stats-counters" class="hero stats-counters">
  <div class="info d-flex align-items-center">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class=" text-center">
          <h2 data-aos="fade-down">lorem</h2>
          <div class="row gy-4">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="background-color: transparent;">
              <div class="stats-item d-flex align-items-center w-100 h-100">
                <div>
                  <span data-purecounter-start="0" data-purecounter-end="232" data-purecounter-duration="1" class="purecounter"></span>
                  <p>Happy Clients</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
              <div class="stats-item d-flex align-items-center w-100 h-100">
                <div>
                  <span data-purecounter-start="0" data-purecounter-end="521" data-purecounter-duration="1" class="purecounter"></span>
                  <p>Projects</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
              <div class="stats-item d-flex align-items-center w-100 h-100">
                <div>
                  <span data-purecounter-start="0" data-purecounter-end="1463" data-purecounter-duration="1" class="purecounter"></span>
                  <p>Orders</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
              <div class="stats-item d-flex align-items-center w-100 h-100">
                <div>
                  <span data-purecounter-start="0" data-purecounter-end="15" data-purecounter-duration="1" class="purecounter"></span>
                  <p>Hard Workers</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="200" href="#get-started" class="btn-get-started">Get Started</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I have made several attempts to enhance the responsiveness of the stats items on my website by implementing various CSS properties, such as flex-wrap, display: flex;, and flex-basis. Additionally, I have utilized the HTML class  to facilitate the creation of a responsive grid layout. Despite investing considerable effort in these endeavors, I have encountered a persistent issue wherein the desired changes fail to manifest on the webpage.

Considering the complexity of modern front-end web development, I am seeking the expertise of experienced professionals who possess a deep understanding of responsive design and CSS flexbox properties. If you have a solid grasp of front-end development principles, I would highly appreciate any valuable insights or recommendations you can provide to address this situation effectively.

Comment: you never addressed the default `col-6` to account for `xs` screens. And as you're redundent then you should simply use `col-6 col-lg-3` instead of `col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6`.

Comment: @tacoshy thank you so much for the helpful answer! It solved my problem. by using col-6 along with col-lg-3 specifying that the column should take up half of the available width on all screen sizes (col-6) and one-fourth of the available width on large screens and above (col-lg-3). this ensures that on smaller screens, now they displayed in two columns.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap Responsive Web Design (RWD)  follows the **mobile-first** concept. 
That in particular means, that stylings for mobile devices have to be addressed first and will be overwritten with styling for larger screens.

In your case, you should start with the mobile styling first. You started with `sm-6` which addresses small screens and applies a column width of 6/12. However, you miss the extra small screens as for cellphones which are `xs`. YOu probably missed it as `xs` isn't used in Bootstrap-5 anymore as a specific breakpoint. As explained above Bootstrap starts with the smallest screens first and then overwrites it on larger screens. That means, that `xs` is the default, and as such no breakpoint is used. As you never used `col-6` to take `xs` screens into account, the default will apply which will be `col-12`.

So you need to add `col-6`:

```html
<element class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6">
```

That will mean that on `xs` and larger screens you will use a column-width of `6/12`, and overwrite it on `sm` and `md` screens with the same value. You only start to change it at `col-lg-3` which means that `sm` and `md` are redundant and not needed.

As a convention, you should also go with the **mobile-first** principle and apply the smaller screen breakpoints first:

```html
<element class="col-6 col-lg-3">
```